# How do I SELECT rows from a table based on a rank value

Tags: sql, select

I have a table with the following (simplified) structure:

```
Order, Status, Sequence
1000, New, 0
1000, Viewed, 1
1000, Shipped, 2
1001, New, 0
1002, New, 0
1002, Viewed, 1
1002, New, 2
```

I want a SELECT statement that will return the row with the max sequence number for each order. So, in the above example, I would want the resulting dataset to be:

```
1000, Shipped, 2
1001, New, 0
1002, New, 2
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I can't seem to construct a WHERE expression that can do it.

To respond to a few comments:

- There are several DMBS in use where this problem arises: MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle and Access.
- There are so many DMBSs involved because the system being developed is consolidating data from other databases in the organization. For this reason I have no control over column names that are reserved words but I am aware of the need to escape the names.
- Many combinations of subqueries, GROUP BY, DISTINCT, MAX and COUNT were tried to no success. Since the query results always end up in Excel I have being grabbing all the rows and sorting and removing duplicates in Excel. My preference is to skip this step by having the SQL query do the work.

Comment: [Try something. Stop being a help vampire.](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Read this before posting question http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Let's not downvote the newcomer to oblivion

Comment: BTW: order is a reserved word. status *might* be a reserved word. Sequence *could* be a reserved word.

Comment: @Jack Maney I can assure you that I have tried many things, all of which failed, which is why I didn't exhaustively list them. We have dealt with this issue mostly by exporting all the data to Excel and sorting and removing duplicates. The ultimate destination of these queries is Excel anyway so this is not overly burdensome but I wanted to know if someone knew a way to do it in SQL.

Comment: @wildplasser Unfortunately I do not have any control over the naming conventions in the databases.

Comment: @JosephRyanGlover there is nothing wrong with using reserved keywords as long as you escaped them. *but it will give you headache in the future*

Comment: @nawfal Thank you for your newcomer compassion. I did read the FAQ before I posted and I don't see how my question violates the principles of proper question asking. Can you expand on your comment so I can improve future questions?

Comment: @Kuya John If our vendors took schema guidance from us the world would be a beautiful place.

Comment: @Blorgbeard This issue has cropped up in our MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle and Access DBs.

Comment: @JosephRyanGlover we've had worse questions, dont worry. But one thing you should have done is post what you have tried and tell us where you're stuck. That gives us more detail, and we can quickly copy paste the code with minor modifications. Questions like `I need this, give me code` doesnt work in SO. You said you tried many things, posting two of them would have earned you upvotes instead of downvotes, seriously..

Comment: BTW, I am pretty sure that my solution works for any of the named DBMS platforms. The usage of reserved words as identifiers may give problems on *some* of them, though.

Comment: @JosephRyanGlover - Well, then, [what, specifically, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) (**Hint:** the previous sentence contains a link. Click on it and read the page to which it points.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL-pattern: finding_the_max can alway be expressed in terms of NOT EXISTS *a bigger one*:

```
SELECT *
FROM ztable zt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ztable nx
    WHERE nx.zorder = zt.zorder
    AND nx.zsequence > zt.zsequence
    );
```

Comment: This query returns the proper result but unfortunately takes too long to execute in Access. I will continue to process the data in Excel.

Comment: It is supposed to run on any decent SQL implementation, and should perform well, given reasonable KEY/index definitions. If excell/access is not one of them, than that's your problem, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

since you haven't mentioned your RDBMS, you can try this query below,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Order, MAX(Sequence) maxValue
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY Order
        ) b ON a.Order = b.Order AND
                a.Sequence = b.maxValue
```

this works on most RDBMS.

if your RDBMS supports `Window Function`, you can do it like this,

```
SELECT  Order, Status, Sequence
FROM
    (
        SELECT  Order, Status, Sequence,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Order 
                                    ORDER BY Sequence DESC)
        FROM    TableName
    ) derivedTable
```

remember that `ORDER` (*also `SEQUENCE` but not all*) is a reserved keyword and must be escaped. The escaped character should depend on what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately Access doesn't support this kind of join (or so it says).